# Registering a bt domain name (bhutan)

Tags: domains

I need to register a domain name that ends in .bt, which is Bhutan. I'm finding a few (expectedly) shady sites that offer it, including rwgusa.com.

Any experience with them or anyone else that can broker an international domain name? This is for a shortener url for my business.

There isn't a whole lot more detail I can add here, but because of the "quality standards" of the stackoverflow stuff, I'm having to add some drivel here. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [registration info page](http://www.nic.bt/?page_id=2) at the official domain registry. They make no reference to third-party registrars, and you didn't name the ones you've found, so I can't address that, (often registries will list a few trusted options) but they do mention "foreign nationals wanting to register a domain with us, could you please send your enquiries to webmaster@druknet.bt" so you might just try going through them instead if you have doubts about the ones you've found. At worst they might be able to direct you to someone reputable.